# c# - Update unit test method with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

I am using the Moq framework for my unit test.
This is my TestMethod:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UpdateContactTests
{
    private static readonly object[] TestValidContact =
    {
        new object[]
        {
            "Prueba", "nearlinx@gmail.com", "86456245",
            new LookUpItem()
            {
                LookUpItemId = Guid.NewGuid(), Category = "ContactType", CategoryId = 1, Value = "Bulling Contact"
            },
            new Company()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Company", Email = "company@gmail.com", WebSite = "company.com",
                Nda = false, Msa = false, Phone = "84876817"
            }
        }
    };

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(TestValidContact))]

    [Test]
    public void UpdateContact_ValidValues_UpdateContact(string name, string email, string phone, LookUpItem lookUpItem, Company company)
    {
        //arrange
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var data =
            new[]
            {
                new Contact { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test1", Email = "nearlinx@gmail.com", Phone = "86456245",
                    ContactType = 
                        new LookUpItem()
                        {
                            LookUpItemId = Guid.NewGuid(), Category = "ContactType", CategoryId = 1, Value = "Bulling Contact"
                        },
                    Company = 
                        new Company()
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Company", Email = "company@gmail.com", WebSite = "company.com",
                            Nda = false, Msa = false, Phone = "84876817"
                        }},
                new Contact { Id = id, Name = "Test2", Email = "nearlinx@gmail.com", Phone = "86456245",
                    ContactType =
                        new LookUpItem()
                        {
                            LookUpItemId = Guid.NewGuid(), Category = "ContactType", CategoryId = 1, Value = "Bulling Contact"
                        },
                    Company =
                        new Company()
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Company", Email = "company@gmail.com", WebSite = "company.com",
                            Nda = false, Msa = false, Phone = "84876817"
                        }},
            };

        var contact = new Contact()
        {
            Id = id,
            Name = name,
            Email = email,
            Phone = phone,
            ContactType = lookUpItem,
            Company = company
        };

        var _unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        _unitOfWork.Setup(mock => mock.Contact.Get(null, null, null)).Returns(data);
        _unitOfWork.Setup(mock => mock.Company.Get(null, null, null)).Returns(new List<Company>());
        _unitOfWork.Setup(mock => mock.LookUpItem.Get(null, null, null)).Returns(new List<LookUpItem>());
        var contactService = new ContactService(_unitOfWork.Object);

        //act
        contactService.UpdateContact(contact);

        //assert
        Assert.That(data.First(m => m.Id == id).Name, Is.EqualTo(contact.Name));
        _unitOfWork.Verify(mock => mock.Contact.Update(It.IsAny<Contact>()), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run the test a `NullReferenceException` is thrown, I suppose it is because the list that has the object that I want to modify is not being assigned

I've never really used Moq and I don't know much about unit tests either, so what am I really doing wrong

Edit:
i change one of the setup because the one called when the update is done was another
instead of

```
_unitOfWork.Setup(mock => mock.Contact.Get(null, null, null)).Returns(data);
```

is

```
_unitOfWork.Setup(mock => mock.Contact.Where(c => c.Id == contact.Id,null,null).FirstOrDefault()).Returns(() => data.Where(c => c.Id == contact.Id));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which line does throw the NRE?

Comment: @PeterCsala this one:
//act
contactService.UpdateContact(contact);

Comment: Based on the shared code fragment it seems like that your `_unitOfWork` is not setup properly. Since `contact` and `contactService` are not null that's why the root cause of NRE is coming from `_unitOfWork`

Comment: How did you define `Contact`, `Company` and `LookUpItem` on the `IUnitOfWork` interface?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest

```
_unitOfWork.Setup(mock => mock.Contact.Get(null, null, null))
```

the mock.Contact returns null

best thing is to debug the test, breakpoint the first line and step through to find exactly where it is throwing the null exception

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
I was doing the set like this

```cs
_unitOfWork.Setup(mock => mock.Contact.Where(c => c.Id == contact.Id,null,null).FirstOrDefault()).Returns(() => data.Where(c => c.Id == contact.Id));
```

while in the update method the condition was this

```cs
_unitOfWork.Setup(mock => mock.Contact.Where(c => c.Id == contact.Id).FirstOrDefault()).Returns(() => data.Where(c => c.Id == contact.Id));
```

changing the condition in the method fixed the problem